# Racket gui key-event: ignore case

Tags: events, scheme, racket

I'm pretty new to racket, and I'm trying to write a game and I'm currently writing my input controller.
I'm using gui/canvas key events (https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/key-event_.html) e.g.

```
(define game-canvas%
  (class canvas%

...

    ;TODO: ignore case
    (define/override (on-char ke)
      (case (send ke get-key-code)
        ['release
           (send controller key-up (send ke get-key-release-code)))
         ]
        [else
           (send controller key-down (send ke get-key-code)))
         ]
        ))

...

    ))

(define dinosaur-controller%
  (class controller%

    ...


    (define/override (key-down key-code)
      (case key-code
        [(#\a)
         (DO STUFF)]))
))
```

However, one problem I have is that the key-codes are case sensitive, e.g. 'a' is different to 'A', so if caps-lock is on, then my controller doesn't work. Is there anyway around this, that would avoid writing `(case key-code [(#\a #\A)])` for every key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a helper function

```
(define (key-downcase-key k)
  (cond
     [(char? k) (char-downcase k)]
     [else      k]))
```

Then use

```
(case (key-downcase k)
  [(#\a) ... as before ...])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realise the key-codes were regular characters.